# How to use Eigen with tf2?

Tags: ros, tf2, ros-jade, ros-indigo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As tf is deprecated, I've started learning how to use tf2.

Unfortunately the documentation and the tutorials are not complete, as the old tf tutorial where.

In particular there's no explanation on how to publish in the most effective way an Eigen transformation throught tf.

The only way I've managed to solve the problem, was writing a boilerplate code, filling a message manually.

This happens as there's no function, as far as I can see, in the tf2_eigen package to convert an Eigen affine3D transformation into a geometry_message.

There seemes to be no documentation for tf2_eigen package. If I'm wrong, can you please point me where I can find the documentation?

And, by the way, the "external conversion" interface (that seemes to be complete only for kdl) is very strange, I would expect a templated broadcaster, in wich i could send an eigen transform like this:

```
broadcaster.sendTransform(eigenTransform, parent_frame, child_frame, timestamp);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223764/how-to-use-eigen-with-tf2?/) by [Boris_il_forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/8606/boris_il_forte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2016-01-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> There seemes to be no documentation for tf2_eigen package. If I'm wrong, can you please point me where I can find the documentation?

[wiki.ros.org/tf2_eigen](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_eigen) → Package Links - Code API → Files → tf2_eigen.h leads to [this](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_eigen/html/tf2__eigen_8h.html) page, which is at least something.

I agree it could use some more actual comments, though.

I suggest to (politely) complain about this on the [geometry_experimental/issues](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues) tracker.

---

Edit:

> And, by the way, the "external conversion" interface (that seemes to be complete only for kdl)

Yes, it would be nice if the `tf2_eigen` package also provided the Eigen version of `tf2::kdlToTransform(..)`. Currently only `tf2::transformToEigen(..)` is there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris_il_forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/8606/boris_il_forte/) on 2016-01-11**:
Yes, I saw the doxygen, but as you say is not so useful. Is completely missing an example of how to use properly the package with tf...

**Comment by [Boris_il_forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/8606/boris_il_forte/) on 2016-01-11**:
opened [issue](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/141)

**Comment by [Boris_il_forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/8606/boris_il_forte/) on 2016-01-11**:
added [pull request](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/pull/142)